# BiqQuery: Remove last N characters

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to remove last 8 characters from a long string but only in case it ends with the 6 character string in the parenthesis (the bolded ones). Does anyone know how to do this in BigQuery?

here are some very random data examples:

- 01/5/2014 - new planted trees - email - juniper
- 04/22/2021 - fridge remote‚I want fresh tea **(xgssjj)**
- re- engagement email
- 5/20 - example reminder **(hfgfgh)**
- repeat customer example #2 **(ttrdgd)**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select longString, 
  trim(regexp_replace(longString, r'\(\w{6}\)$', '')) newString
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: use trim() function for this  - see update in answer